# Can javers completely delete an object (together with all its history)?

Tags: javers

I am new to javers and evaluating it for our new project. We have use cases that we want to use javers to track our domain objects when they are alive, but when they are deleted for a while (configurable period), we would like to be able to cleanup the space, either by on-demand calling an API to completely wiped out the deleted object all together with its history, or configure a retention policy to cleanup terminated objects older than a certain period automatically. Is this possible? Or did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature. Complete wipe out of a given object would be useful. It's not hard to implement. If you'd contribute a PR, we will merge it.